# How do I add Code to scikit-learn package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have .py files with classes that I want to add to the neural_network package of scikit-learn. I pasted my .py files and tried to import a class from one of them but it failed. What am I doing wrong? Do i need compiled version of each new file as well?

Comment: Do you mean you want to *contribute* to the project? Or... what, exactly?

Comment: How did you install scikit-learn, and what operating system do you use?

Comment: I am trying to implement a MultilayerPerceptronClassifier from https://github.com/IssamLaradji/NeuralNetworks/tree/master/multilayer_perceptron into my PC's Anaconda scikit-learn package under neural_networks. I want to use a class from the multilayer_perceptron class in python

Comment: What was the exact error message or any sign of malfunction? How was exactly when "but it failed" as you wrote?

Comment: if you run python with multiple verbose flags, what happens? (ie, `python -vv` and then try to import things.)